# Wrong Name on a taskbar for a Windows Form app on Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, taskbar

I created a windows form app in Visual Basic, the name of the app is "Example_1".

The name of the solution is "Example_1"

The name of the project is "Example_1"

The Text on the form is "Example_1"

The assembly name is "Example_1"

**What is the problem?**, well at my first try to do this app, I created it as the name of "Example_0" which I have been changing through all the properties to show the new name "Example_1".

Somehow, when I run the app, in the taskbar appears the correct name or if I put my mouse above it, it says "Example_1", in the correct way.

**BUT**, if I Right-clicked over the icon in the taskbar, it says "Example_0", WHY!

I have already checked all the app properties and nowhere it says "Example_0"

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the old name into the "Assembly Info".
Expand your project in solution exporer, then double click "My Project".
In the Application tab you will have the "Application info" button.